# How to return a list of all the indexes in the string that have capital letters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I want to return a list of all the indexes in a string that have capital letters. So far I am able to create a list of all the values instead of their indices with a list comprehension. E.g.
the string `"HeLlO"` should output `[0, 2, 4]`

Here's what I got:

```
def capital_indexes(str):
    return [x for x in str if x.isupper()]
```

Output is `['H', 'L', 'O']`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to get the indices:

```
def capital_indexes(string):
    return [i for i, char in enumerate(string) if char.isupper()]

print(capital_indexes("HeLlO")) # [0, 2, 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this :

```
def capital_indexes(str_val):
    return [i for i in range(len(str_val)) if str_val[i].isupper()]

print(capital_indexes('HeLlO'))
```

PLEASE NOTE : Do not use `str` for your variable names . It is a reserved keyword .

Comment: It's not a reserved keyword but a builtin name. A reserved keyword is something like `if`, `def` etc.